# Can not get Codemirror textarea Values on multiple elements using js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

I'm trying to get the values of my textarea codemirror to send in a json to the server to save them after edit, but I can't select the ELEMENT...I tried also getting the element by id...same thing. I get this:

> Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://esironal.github.io/cmtouch/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://esironal.github.io/cmtouch/lib/codemirror.css">
    <script src="http://esironal.github.io/cmtouch/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<div><textarea class="yyyyyy232" id="scripttextarea_1"></textarea><button type="submit" class='yy4e' id='btn_1'>Save1</button></div>
<div><textarea class="yyyyyy232" id="scripttextarea_2"></textarea><button type="submit" class='yy4e' id='btn_2'>Save2</button></div>
<div><textarea class="yyyyyy232" id="scripttextarea_3"></textarea><button type="submit" class='yy4e' id='btn_3'>Save3</button></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        myTextarea=document.getElementsByClassName('yyyyyy232');
        console.log($(myTextarea).length);

            for (i=0;i<myTextarea.length;i++){

                cm=CodeMirror.fromTextArea($(myTextarea[i])[0], {
                    mode: "python",
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    lineWrapping: true,
                    indentUnit: 4,
                    height: 400
                });
            };
});


$('.yy4e').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            ppp=$(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
            xx=document.getElementById("scripttextarea_"+ppp);

                cm=CodeMirror.fromTextArea(xx).getValue();
                console.log(cm);

          $.getJSON('/edit_scripts',{
               'command' : cm
           },function(data){
               console.log('edited');
            })
        });

</script>
```

Some help would really be great, as this problem is bugging me for some good hours. Thank you

Comment: Which line is that error caused by?

Comment: cm=CodeMirror.fromTextArea(xx).getValue(); getting the value...

Comment: the problem is the textarea you defined is override by CodeMirror codes and actually the textarea you initialized is currently hide...

Comment: yes and I don't know how to save the codemirror value as you type in, to correct textarea and get it from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            myTextarea=document.getElementsByClassName("yyyyyy232");
            console.log($(myTextarea).length);
            var cm = new Array();
                 for (i=0;i<myTextarea.length;i++){

                    cm[i]=CodeMirror.fromTextArea($(myTextarea[i])[0], {
                        mode: "python",
                        lineNumbers: true,
                        lineWrapping: true,
                        indentUnit: 4,
                        height: 400
                    });
                };

                $(".yy4e").on("click",function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            ppp=$(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
                            numcode= parseInt(ppp)-1;
                             xx=$("#scripttextarea_"+ppp).attr("id");
                             console.log(xx);


                              var   Code=cm[numcode].getValue();
                                console.log(Code);

                          $.getJSON("/test",{
                               "command" : cm[numcode]
                           },function(data){
                               console.log("edited");
                            })
                        });


    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://esironal.github.io/cmtouch/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://esironal.github.io/cmtouch/lib/codemirror.css">
        <script src="http://esironal.github.io/cmtouch/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <div><textarea class="yyyyyy232" id="scripttextarea_1"></textarea><button type="submit" class="yy4e" id="btn-1">Save1</button></div>
    <div><textarea class="yyyyyy232" id="scripttextarea_2"></textarea><button type="submit" class="yy4e" id="btn-2">Save2</button></div>
    <div><textarea class="yyyyyy232" id="scripttextarea_3"></textarea><button type="submit" class="yy4e" id="btn-3">Save3</button></div>
```

this is a working example of your code 
you have several problem one is mention above about btn name 
second on click out of document ready 
third you identify all code mirror as on value cm and it shall be array cm[]
you need to call  text area value by cm[] array number

Answer (score 0):

Check here:

```
ppp=$(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
```

And see here:

```
<div>
    <textarea class="yyyyyy232" id="scripttextarea_1"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class='yy4e' id='btn1'>Save1</button>
</div>
```

**btn1** could not be split by '**_**' and it will be fine that you replace **btn1** to **bth_1**.

Remind: You may try to print out the value step by step by yourself first.

Comment: Edited my question...it was supposed to be with btn_1 and it dosen't work like that too...I find the correct id...and use cm=CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementByID(xx)).getValue(); - same thing

Comment: What is your question at the moment?